# spring security not able to add custom authentication providers

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created additional authentication providers. I am registering them like following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAP());
        auth.authenticationProvider(usernameAndPasswordAP());
        auth.userDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
    }
```

Later in my code I am using AuthenticationManager to authenticate users. The issue is that I have only one authentication provider registered in authentication manager which is DaoAuthenticationProvider. It looks like my authentication providers are not registered at all. Should I do some additional config to make it work? I am using spring boot 1.2.6 Thanks in advance for any tips. Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`, the underlying AuthenticationManager is exposed in one of 2 ways:

1) within SecurityConfig, you can simply call `authenticationManager()`

2) if you need AuthenticationManager outside of your SecurityConfig you will need to expose it as a bean, for example:

```
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAP());
        auth.authenticationProvider(usernameAndPasswordAP());
        auth.userDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
    }

   @Bean
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way we have authentication providers configured in our Spring Boot web applications is similar to what is discussed in [the example Spring Security Java configuration from the current release reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#hello-web-security-java-configuration), which modifies the default autowired `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. Using your methods, it might look like:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAP())
    .authenticationProvider(usernameAndPasswordAP())
    .userDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
}
```

If I am reading [the Javadocs for the configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) method](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)) correctly, when you override this method you must specify your own `AuthenticationManager`. By using the autowired instance as described above, the default `AuthenticationManager` (which is `ProviderManager`, which in turn delegates to one or more configured `AuthorizationProvider` instances).

You may also need to annotate your configuration class with:

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
```

So that your access control rules are applied before the defaults that Spring Boot will otherwise configure for you.